# Java Button not appearing on (GUI)

Tags: java, class, user-interface, interface, frame

I've been figuring out a nice way to lay nice foundations when working on a somewhat bigger project than I have before. If i write everything in main it works fine. When doing classes like this the Frame works but the Button i've added doesn't wanna appear:

//main

```
package taxsystem;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Taxmain
{
    public mainFrame mf;
    public Interface gui;

    public void startApplication()
    {
        mf = new mainFrame();
        mf.startApp();
        gui = new Interface();
        gui.makeLayout();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Taxmain tm = new Taxmain();
        tm.startApplication();
    }
}
```

//The actual Frame

```
package taxsystem;


import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainFrame extends JFrame
{
    public void startApp()
    {
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(720,340);
        setLocation(0,0);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        setTitle("Tax Handler");
    }
}
```

//the layout (where i create the button that doesn't appear)

```
package taxsystem;


import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Interface extends JPanel
{
    Taxmain mc;
    public JButton testButton;

    public void makeLayout()
    {
        testButton = new JButton();
        testButton.setText("Printer");

        testButton.setFont(new Font("verdana", Font.ITALIC, 16));
        testButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        testButton.setFocusable(false);
        testButton.setSize(new Dimension(150, 40));
        testButton.setLocation(10, 10);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.add(testButton);   
    }
}
```

Currently it looks like this: https://gyazo.com/fad5dbca6c59905faea0a8ac1fbd424a

Thanks in advance, also are there anyway i can improve the code i have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the JPanel to your JFrame

```
public void startApplication()
{
    mf = new mainFrame();
    mf.startApp();
    gui = new Interface();
    gui.makeLayout();
    mf.add(gui); // here is get's added
}
```